# disable div with php

Tags: php, html, css

I use foreach php for my blog. All elements in the foreach php are repeating (the number of articles). But only for a div, I would like this div is not repeating.

The div I would like no repeating is id="wrapper". But for the elements inside, I would like they repeating.

How I can do ?

```
<ul>

    <?php foreach($posts as $key => $value): ?>

    <li>

        <a>

            <div class="text">

                <h1><?php echo $key ?></h1>

            </div>

            <div id="wrapper"> <!-- I don't want this ID "wrapper" repeating -->

                <section id="frame" ><?php echo $value->post_title; ?>

                    <h2><?php echo $value->post_title; ?></h2>

                </section>

            </div> 
        </a>

    </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: what is $key content? Auto index starting from 0 or id from database? (will be helper for the answer)

Comment: You don't want <div id="wrapper"> opening and </div> closing lines but content, right? It will be only printed for the first post?

Comment: You can't you would have to take the wrapper out of the loop. Add the reason why you want to take the wrapper out of the loop to your answer. If it is styling, add the styling to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if it's the first iteration (using a boolean), and if it's the first time, show that `<div>` element.

```
<ul>
    <?php $first_time = true; foreach($posts as $key => $value): ?>
    <li>
        <a>
            <div class="text">
                <h1><?php echo $key ?></h1>
            </div>

            <?php if($first_time): ?>
            <div id="wrapper"> <!-- I don't want this ID "wrapper" repeating -->
            <?php endif; ?>

                <section id="frame"><?php echo $value->post_title; ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $value->post_title; ?></h2>
                </section>

            <?php if($first_time): ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </a>
    </li>
    <?php $first_time = false; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

To better solve the question that I suspect you're having, use a class of wrapper and frame instead of an ID (and adjust any CSS definitions)